# Has anyone integrated the Rome2rio travel widget onto their site?

Tags: api, integration

Iam looking to integrate the Rome2rio as a widget onto my travel portal. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: when you get it please let me know also , i am working on the same kind of thing

Answer (score 0):

yes i have just registered to get API key from rome2rio and read the documentation of API here [documentation](https://www.rome2rio.com/documentation)

below are the two ways of calling either XML or json whatever you want in responce

```
http://<server>/api/1.2/xml/Search?key=<key>&oName=Bern&dName=Zurich

http://<server>/api/1.2/json/Search?key=<key>&oName=Bern&dName=Zurich
```